# Connect laptop and android via bluetooth(labview)

Tags: android, bluetooth, labview

I want to connect a laptop with android via bluetooth.

What I want to do is send numeric value from android application to Labview program installed on the laptop.

The android program returns value which changes according to the button click (e.g. when I press the up button, value +1).

I want to send this value to the laptop via bluetooth.

I was looking for google, stackoverflow and other many communities, but I couldn't find any hints or solutions.

I used "blueterm" application (Which enables android to connect with bluetooth devices) to connect laptop and android, but the laptop rejects the incoming connection!.

The program which needs to receive the data is LabView.

```
package com.u2ring.control;

import com.u2ring.control.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.webkit.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button Plus, Minus;
TextView Value;
TextView url;
int score = 0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
Minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);

Value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);

String host = getString(R.string.host);

Plus.setOnClickListener(this);
Minus.setOnClickListener(this);
Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Secondpage.class);
        startActivity(in);
        }
});};




public void onClick(View v)
{
boolean showText = false;

int id = v.getId();
if (id == R.id.up) {
    score++;
    showText = true;
} else if (id == R.id.down) {
    score--;
    showText = true;
} else if (id == R.id.number) {
    showText = true;
}
if(showText)
Value.setText(String.valueOf(score));

WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
wv.loadUrl("http://10.16.27.184:8080/admin/speed/"+Integer.toString(score));
}
}
```

Comment: Here you're just trying to open a web page, where is your bluetooth code?

Comment: I'm showing my code... I asked here because I don't know how to connect bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had found this topic earlier. I had the same problem long time ago. And there was no possibility to connect phone with laptop using bluetooth directly. 
There was only a way to send files, while mobile phone was seen in as a container (basically folder).

The solution is really simple. Just implement VI in LabVIEW that will pass data by built in bluetooth components (It has to be VI build for desktop application (windows), because on hardware bluetooth is not supported by default).

After that simple trick you will be able to receive data using bluetooth.

Also, consider TCP IP protocole which will work simply much better :)